# Is it possible to ship a docker image as part of an application?

Tags: docker, deployment

I'm currently using docker to deploy my backend on cloud, but am also looking into building an offline app with the backend code bundled with the frontend ui. Would it be possible to simply ship the same docker image or convert it to a platform-specific executable somehow?

Comment: You could push your image(s) to Docker Hub and your end users could run them like any other image(s).  But they would fundamentally (a) need Docker and (b) need administrator-level permissions to run your application.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry, I should clarify, I'd like the user to be able to use my application without having to install Docker. For instance, if they start the application in offline mode, then I can start up the backend process as an executable instead of requiring Docker. Is this possible?

Comment: You need Docker installed to run Docker images.  You might look at compiled languages like Go that have a way to embed artifacts into a single binary, or setups like a typical Java application where the UI can be embedded in a `.jar` or `.war` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze What I mean is that we already have a backend built (in Python) and we are deploying this with docker on our backend (using Kubernetes). What I wanted to know was if it's possible to package a docker runtime with the application executable -- in effect, packaging the backend without much additional work. I'm not interested in rewriting our entire backend in a different compiled language.

Comment: Would an answer to this other SO question − [Is there a way to compile a Python program to binary and use it with a Scratch Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62581924/9164010) − be a solution for your use case?

Answer (score -1):

You can export image to file and import it anywhere.

```
docker image save <REPOSITORY> > <filename>
docker image import <path to file> <repository-name>
```

Comment: Beware: `import` is not the counterpart of `save`, you should rather mention `load`, because `import` will only load the filesystem, not a proper image. See: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/docker-import-export-vs-load-save (Also, the `image` subcommand is unneeded)

Comment: Doesn't this still require the user to have Docker installed? To clarify, I want the user to be able to open an executable (.exe or .app) and for the docker image to just launch, without the user having to install Docker. Is this possible?